# Show that no sequence in $X\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ converges to $(0,0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I have been reading general topology by John L. Kelley and came across this problem in chapter 2. E.

Let $X$ be the set of all non-negative integer pairs with the topology described as follows:

For each point $(m,n)\neq (0,0)$ the set $\{(m,n)\}$ is open. A set U is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ if and only if for all but a finite number of integers $m$. The set $\{n|(m,n)\notin U\}$ is finite. (Visualizing X in the Euclidean plane, a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains all but a finite number of members of all but a finite number of columns.

The Question:

d) Show that no sequence in $X\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ converges to $(0,0)$.

My Work:

Suppose some sequence $S_n$ in $X\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ converges to $(0,0)$ then $S_n$ is eventually in each neighborhood of $(0,0)$. This implies that $S_n$ has only a finite number of members in each column since each neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ is the complement of a finite number of columns, hence $S_n$ contains a finite number of members in an infinite number of columns. Note there are also neighborhoods that are complements of a finite number of different columns and so by the same logic, $S_n$ contains a finite number of members in every column.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This post is duplicate. The part in parentheses "(Visualizing ...)" doesn't agree with the definition of the topology. It should be that only finitely many columns are missing infinitely many points. If the topology were as in the description in parentheses, then any sequence that doesn't repeat any value infinitely many times, would converge to $(0,0)$.

Comment: @user85667 I am quoting the textbook. I believe that it does agree with the definition of the topology as a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ contains all but a finite number of members of all but a finite number of columns. Meaning that $U$ is missing a finite number of points from an infinite number of columns and an infinite number of points from a finite number of columns. Which is exactly how the topology is described above.

Comment: I see. I didn't read this post carefully and I think in the previous it wasn't. You only need to study two cases. If the projection of the sequence to the first coordinate repeats a value $x$ infinitely many times, then $\{(x,n),\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}^c$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ that no tail of the sequence will be completely inside it. If the projection never repeats any value infinitely many times (note that this means that the sequences hits each column finitely many times),then the complement of the values of the sequence is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and the sequence is completely outside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequence in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\cup\{(0,0)\}$ with $(0,0)$ as accumulation point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345402/sequence-in-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-cup-0-0-with-0-0-as-accumulati)